# how to move git storage space from SSD to hard disk

Tags: git, solid-state-drive

In my new PC, I have both SSD and hard disk. My guess is that it would be a luxury to waste SSD storage space for my old files. How can I redirect a `git init` to use my hard disk for storage?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Futhermore, I think option --separate-git-dir should be added to the help.

Comment: I *do* see that option when I run `git init -h`, and on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.

Comment: Well, I was not sure what "git init" makes, with "-h"